# Cannot push to github: constant errors, hanging, disconnect

Tags: git, github

Hours and hours on this, I for some reason, absolutely cannot push to github.

I was re-added a few days ago to an organizations group, and re-added my SSH key in github settings...

Key appears to be working by running:

```
ssh -T git@github.com
```

I then get:

```
Hi meatcorpname! You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not provide shell access.
```

But it continually hangs and eventually gives up on *writing objects*, after a painful large chunk of 5-10 minutes.

**Goal:** I have a local project I am working on, I am simply just trying to port it on the organization's github. I have created the repo name, and set the origin a dozen or so times, via SSH and HTTPS, all confirmed each time via `git remote -v`. I have completely removed and/or re-wrote the remote origin path, trying various ways, multiple times.

The most consistent error, I get is: **fatal: the remote end hung up unexpectedly**

```
Total 229 (delta 70), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 0
fatal: the remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

But occasionally I have received things like this:

```
remote: fatal: pack exceeds maximum allowed size (2.00 GiB)
send-pack: unexpected disconnect while reading sideband packet
```

This is a small website, with a JS, CSS, and modest image folder... Not large by any means for Github. There is also a video folder container 6 .mp4 videos, which I suppose somewhat large.. Anyway, I tried removing the videos from git tracking, then removing the folder entirely, and re-pushing, still hangs and gives up.

Most recently I have tried:

```
git config --global http.version HTTP/1.1
```

Nothing.

```
git config --global http.postBuffer 157286400
```

Nothing.

```
using --Force flag with push command(s).
```

Nothing.

```
GIT_CURL_VERBOSE=1 git push
```

Nothing.

**Anything left I can try to simply push my local project to a defined, new, github repo?**

Comment: Does this only happen with this one repo, or with all repos in this organization?

Comment: Also, you might try `GIT_TRACE_PACKET=true git push` to get more information.

Comment: Finally, if it's a size issue or an issue of video files not being completely pruned from objects, you can try `git gc` before your next push.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Transfer the ownership of the repo through Github's tools
https://docs.github.com/en/enterprise-server@3.3/repositories/creating-and-managing-repositories/transferring-a-repository

Or fork the Repo and then delete the link to the fork and done.

To manage big files in Git you need the following extension:
https://git-lfs.com/

Comment: It can't be a size issue as I have tried pushing without the video folder

Comment: But you've committed those files though right? Can you start from scratch (new repository) and just push one file at a time? I think this will work, and then you can try 10 files at a time, or even more, as long as you don't try to push too much at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps try using Git LFS?
https://git-lfs.com/

Here is a guide on how to install it:
https://docs.github.com/en/repositories/working-with-files/managing-large-files/installing-git-large-file-storage

And here is how to add files to it:
https://docs.github.com/en/repositories/working-with-files/managing-large-files/moving-a-file-in-your-repository-to-git-large-file-storage

Answer (score 1):

Git is not designed for such large packs of data. You got the error message saying that the data that you're trying to push exceeds the maximum allowed size of 2 GiB, which means it could be much larger than that:

```
remote: fatal: pack exceeds maximum allowed size (2.00 GiB)
```

You may want to try [Git LFS](https://git-lfs.com/) which stands for "large file storage", or to push the larger files one at a time.